# Excel 365 in Teams/Sharepoint does not open the correct revision in one of my shared files (only one person in my team)

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, version-history, microsoft-teams

It is a very difficult to explain the issue, neither the IT person in my company is able to find the problem.

We stored three `.xlsx` files in SharePoint. Me and my team has access to it and we update it everyday.

One of the team member has a problem in only one of the files, when he opens the file he always sees an old revision such a week before.

If I or any other team member opens the same file in Teams/SharePoint it shows correctly!

Is there some buffer/cache or other thing storage in his computer which doesn't permit the file open correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be very sure of the steps needed to reproduce this.  Without further information, it will be hard to answer.

There is a possibility of caching, but it could be in browser, Excel, network kit, internet service provider, Onedrive Sync client.  They could be using a bookmark to a specific version.

Record with screenshots what the person is doing.  Note down browser, operating system, version of Excel, location, type of connection etc.

Follow these exact steps yourself when logged into your own machine and preferably ALSO when logged into theirs (could be an incognito window in browser and you remoting in somehow, even via skype/teams).  They can then try on their account on your machine in the same way.  Do not share passwords, do not compromise security.

If you have access to additional machines, try these.

See if they can use your way of accessing the file using a different browser.

You are looking to fault find and differentiate on every aspect of their connection.

Comment: Hello Rob, I understand your questions regarding the variables we could have however, I  can tell you everybody has the same excel365 version installed and use the same system/server/internet connection. I open the file by MicrosoftTeams in my machine and I see the up to date file and this happen with the other colleagues, but this specific person open using the same  method in another machine but he see an older revision with old data such week ago.